# Convert adjacency matrix to specific edge list in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

If I have the matrix

```
  1 0 0  
  0 0 1 
  0 0 0
```

and I want this form in MATLAB

```
1 2 3  1 2 3  1 2 3
1 1 1  2 2 2  3 3 3
1 0 0  0 0 0  0 1 0
```

also I want the values of third row in result. i.e. `ans= [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go -

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2));
out = [X(:).' ; Y(:).' ; A(:).']
```

For the last part of your question, use the last row of `out` : `out(end,:)` or `A(:).'`.

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
>> [X,Y] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2));
>> out = [X(:).' ; Y(:).' ; A(:).']
out =
     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: What about editing that to use the `size()` instead of just `1:3` for the sake of generalism?

Comment: Thank you very much , Divaker and Adriaan

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng for taking care of it!